# Compute inverse Laplace transform

Tags: inverse-laplace

Compute the inverse Laplace transform of

$$\frac{3s +1}{{s^{3}}+{4s^{2}}+{(k-3)}}$$

Already tried with partial fraction expansion, without success.

Comment: Why did partial fraction expansion fail?

Comment: @MarkViola As of my approach , the polynomial $${{s^{3}}+{4s^{2}}+{(k-3)}}$$  is not completely reducible by the numerator $${3s +1}$$   It has format $$D(s)=N(s)Q(s) + R(s)$$ , where D(s) is : $${{s^{3}}+{4s^{2}}+{(k-3)}}$$ , N(s) = $${3s +1}$$ , Q(s) is the quotient polynomial and R(s) is the remainder polynomial

Comment: See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots:_Nature_and_derivation).

Comment: Regardless of the coefficients, the roots of any cubic polynomial can be found in closed form.  The location of the roots obviously depend on $k$.